# Data ordering issue in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

got a small little problem I'm hoping someone can help me with.

I have the following dataset in MYSQL:

```
SELECT * FROM account;

pk  |  customer
1   |   1
2   |   0
3   |   1
```

I only need the customer column BUT I need it to be in the same order as above e.g.:

```
customer
1
0
1
```

However whenever I try and perform the following command, I get the following:

```
SELECT customer FROM account

customer
0
1
1
```

I have already tried the following with no luck:

```
SET @rownum=0;
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum+1 as rank, customer FROM account

rank |  customer
1    |   0
2    |   1
3    |   1
```

UPDATE: I forgot to add something important.  I can't rely on ordering by the primary key, mainly because the primary key could be a varchar and not integer in some circumstances.

I need the order in which the data was inserted in the database. When I do the same query returning varchar values it is in the correct order.

Any ideas?

**Answer: [SQL query no order by question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541907/sql-query-no-order-by-question)**

Comment: you want to order your result according Pk column

Comment: The pk cannot be both an integer and a varchar.. it may be a varchar containing an integer in varchar form.

Comment: Again fully aware that a primary key must be a designated datatype such as char, varchar, integer etc and it can be cast/converted to another. I meant that performing a similiar query returning a list of varchar values they had appeared in the same order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT customer FROM account ORDER BY pk ASC
```

Comment: Hi Evan - Sorry I forgot to add something important. I can't rely on ordering by the primary key. Mainly because the primary key could be a  varchar and not integer in some circumstances.

Comment: Just beat me, don't think you need the ASC though!

Comment: @LewisWheeler then why have you asked to have the same order? If not by PK then by what?

Comment: @LewisWheeler: You can't rely on "default" (what it looks like to you) ordering in a table.

Comment: ... I guess that means the pk type is varchar, in which case it will still work.

Comment: I just added in an update which explains it - basically I need the order in which the data was inserted into the database.

Comment: @LewisWheeler: Then either use a primary key that is an integer or add a timestamp field and sort it using that.

Comment: Can't do that Evan the possible database's im dealing with are outside my control.

Comment: @Arth - it is good practice to add the `ASC` even though it is the default as it makes the intentions of the developer clear.

Comment: @LewisWheeler - in that case you're screwed! RDBMSs can insert into different positions based on holes left from previous deletes so you cannot rely on rows being returned in the order they were originally inserted. You will either have to sort out the `problem` with the PKs or add a timestamp.

Comment: @LewisWheeler: What nnichols said.

Comment: Just found something which explains what I want to do isn't possible. It seems it was luck which meant the varchar value I selected didn't perform the same way.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541907/sql-query-no-order-by-question

Comment: @LewisWheeler sounds like you need to contact the DBA and tell them to start A'ing their DB.

Comment: @LewisWheeler: That's what I said in the fourth comment here.

Comment: @nnichols - true but I think there is a point when you have to assume that your intentions are clear with an understanding of the language that you are using.. plus there are always comments!

Comment: Yes Evan i'm aware of that now (Your comment made me go looking) - however its one thing to say something but its a very different thing to actually explain it; which is what the other guy did. 

The link I provided explained to me how in one circumstance what I wanted seem to happen naturally and in another how it didn't - something your answer didn't explain.

Comment: @LewisWheeler: My answer didn't explain that because it was based on the information provided in your question at that time. Feel free to answer your own question with the information you have found and an explanation.

Comment: UPDATE: Screw it I updated my question with link to that answer ill just add this answer as correct. Can't do that yet due to reputation. Ill wait 8 hours and answer it or your welcome to post your answer and ill click it correct. 

Your right - my question wasn't the best in the world it was based on my lack of knowledge of exactly ordering of data occurred when it was inserted.

Thanks for all the comments guys.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM account
ORDER BY pk;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define the order without selecting that column. So, use this

```
SELECT `customer` from `account` ORDER BY `pk` ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this sql:

```
SELECT customer FROM account order by PK
```

Comment: I'd capitalize the ORDER BY and lower case the pk.